# Reduce the size of the card cover of a Trello board

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Any way to reduce the size of the card cover on Trello?

It seems like the only option is to remove it.

[image]

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You need to attach a picture with a greater width/height ratio. Try using a resize service like http://cloudinary.com/ when attaching.

---

### Why?

Trello will always try to show your picture with the width of a card, which is fixed. If the image has a low width/height ratio, the image will stretch to the top until it makes the width equal to the card width, looking bigger. And vice-versa.

Comment: firesize seems to no longer exist fyi. Can you also explain why the height / width ratio makes a difference? why would 4:3 be larger than 16:9 for example?

Comment: I've updated the answer.